# SQLAlchemy relationship with join

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, model, fastapi

I am coding a pet project of the social network. I have 2 tables "users", "friendships". In order to become friends user 1 needs to send a request to user 2, when user 2 accepts it they become friends (user 1 doesn't follow user 2, they become mutual friends). I am storing friend pairs as Adjacency List Model (maybe you can recommend more efficient way)

```
users
+----+-------+
| ID | Name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | John  |
| 2  | Alice |
+----+-------+

friendships
+---------+-----------+---------+
| user_id | friend_id |  status |
+---------+-----------+---------+
|   1     |    2      | accepted|
|   2     |    1      | accepted|
+---------+-----------+---------+
```

Here you can see models in SQLAlchemy

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, server_default=text("uuid_generate_v4()"), nullable=False)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    fullname = Column(String, nullable=False)
    
    is_active = Column(Boolean, server_default="False", nullable=True, )
    last_login = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=True)

    # ! needs research
    friends = relationship("Friendship", primaryjoin=(
        "and_(User.id==Friendship.requester_id, Friendship.status=='accepted')"
    ))


class Friendship(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'friendships'

    class StatusEnum(enum.Enum):
        sent = 'sent'
        pending = 'pending'
        declined = 'declined'
        accepted = 'accepted'
        blocked = 'blocked'

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, server_default=text("uuid_generate_v4()"), nullable=False)

    requester_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    addressee_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)

    status = Column(Enum(StatusEnum), server_default=StatusEnum.sent.value, nullable=False, )
    request_date = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), server_default=func.now(), nullable=False)
    accept_date = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), server_default=None, nullable=True)
```

I have defined relationships in the model, so I can query friends using

```py
user.friends
```

However, I receive only columns of the friendships table, but I want to receive information of the friend from users table

Current result

```json
    {
        "request_date": "2023-07-01T17:38:41.307703+03:00",
        "id": "48533dfa-bc02-4ae0-92d9-7ec7086b3646",
        "requester_id": "66c9509f-0a22-4ba8-be57-808a6aea0d52",
        "addressee_id": "3e88e2a6-e2b5-4057-bce6-7f2b284aff63",
        "status": "accepted",
        "accept_date": "2023-07-02T18:12:19.052639+03:00"
    }
```

Expected

```json
    {
        "request_date": "2023-07-01T17:38:41.307703+03:00",
        "id": "48533dfa-bc02-4ae0-92d9-7ec7086b3646",
        "requester_id": "66c9509f-0a22-4ba8-be57-808a6aea0d52",
        "addressee_id": "3e88e2a6-e2b5-4057-bce6-7f2b284aff63",
        "status": "accepted",
        "accept_date": "2023-07-02T18:12:19.052639+03:00",
        ----- new fields -----
        "username": "entl",
        "is_active": "True",
     
        other fields of users table
        ...
    }
```

I tried to research but couldn't find the way how to join the table inside relationship (maybe simple session.query(...).join() will be more efficient)

Here is the sql query which I try to rebuilt inside relationship.

```sql
SELECT * FROM friendships AS f 
LEFT JOIN users ON f.addressee_id = users.id 
WHERE f.requester_id = {id_of_the_current_user};
```

I am just learning to design database and query, so maybe I have inefficient way of storing friendships. In addition, I know how to make a query to database using session.query, but it seems to me that using relationship will be more convenient and I will not have many queries to database later.

UPD:
Only solution I managed to find

```py
    @property
    def get_friends(self):
        return select(Friendship, User)\
            .join(User, Friendship.addressee_id == User.id)\
            .filter(and_(Friendship.requester_id == self.id,
                         Friendship.status == "accepted"))
```